# keyup and keydown events, if user is typing too fast

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't know how to solve this problem:

The user can start typing some numeric values in the input fields. The cursor will move to the next input field, after typing a number.
But it doesn't work, if the user is typing too fast, that means if there is no keyup between two numbers.

So if the user is typing "12" - instead of "1" and "2" -, there should be the value "1" in the first input field, value "2" in the second input field and the focus should be set to the third input field.

```
<form>
    <input type="password" maxlength="1" name="pin1" autofocus />
    <input type="password" maxlength="1" name="pin2" />
    <input type="password" maxlength="1" name="pin3" />
    <input type="password" maxlength="1" name="pin4" />
</form>

$('form input').on('keydown', function(event) {        
    if (event.shiftKey || event.which <= 47 || event.which >= 58)
        return false;

}).on('keyup', function (event) {
    if (event.currentTarget.value.length >= 1)
        $(event.currentTarget).next('input').focus();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bbeg17r8/

Comment: Why not build one input for 4 digits? Is it because of the way you display those digits? If so, then maybe you should solve that in a different way, or make a consession instead of risking reduced user experience.

Comment: Firstly, you should use `keypress` event, not `keydown`. Depending type of keyboard, `keydown` could return unexpected behaviour, it shouldn't be used for `character` checking.

Comment: Do you need to support older browsers (IE8 e.g) or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried with `input` event combining both conditions and it will work for multiple user actions like `key events`, `cut/paste events` etc.:

```js
$('form input').on('input keypress', function(event) {     
    if (event.type == "keypress" && (event.shiftKey || event.which <= 47 || event.which >= 58))
        return false;


    if (event.currentTarget.value.length >= 1)
        $(event.currentTarget).next('input').focus();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <input type="password" maxlength="1" name="pin1" autofocus />
    <input type="password" maxlength="1" name="pin2" />
    <input type="password" maxlength="1" name="pin3" />
    <input type="password" maxlength="1" name="pin4" />
</form>
```

Comment: But this will let the user typing all characters. I need to allow only numeric values.

Comment: `input` event isn't a keyboard event, it doesn't handle `event.which`, `event.shiftKey` etc...

Comment: Ah! as noted by **A.Wolff** you can add one more event `keypress` to it. @user3142695

Comment: The last question on that: I do get to the next input after typing a value. And everything is working fine. But if I hit `backspace` I would like to go to the previous input and remove that content: `if (event.type == "keypress" && event.which === 8) $(event.currentTarget).prev('input').focus();` But this doesn't work.

Comment: `if (event.type == "keypress") console.log(event.which);` doesn't give me a value, if I hit backspace. But I do get values for every character... I don't understand that..

Comment: `event.which <= 47 ` is causing this. @user3142695.

Comment: Thanks so much @Jai

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to be a fair bit more sophisticated to handle this well, particular if the user uses paste to enter their PIN (which they shouldn't, but will).

I would remove the `maxlength` and distribute the text across the inputs on entry. `keypress` is the best event for dealing with actual textual keypresses, and then of course we'll want `change` and `input`.

Here's a rough-and-ready version:

```
$('input').on('keypress input change', function(event) {
    setTimeout(handleInputs, 0);
});
function handleInputs() {
  var focussed = false;
  var inputs = $("input").get();

  // Collect the values
  var text = inputs.reduce(
    function(acc, input) {
      return acc + input.value;
    },
    ""
  );

  // ...adjust `text` here if you want...

  // Distribute the values
  inputs.forEach(function(input, index) {
    input.value = text.charAt(index);
    if (!focussed && !input.value) {
      console.log("Focussing " + this.name);
      input.focus();
      focussed = true;
    }
  });
}
```

**Live Example:**

```js
$('input').on('keypress input change', function(event) {
 setTimeout(handleInputs, 0);
});
function handleInputs() {
  var focussed = false;
 var inputs = $("input").get();
 var text = inputs.reduce(
    function(acc, input) {
      return acc + input.value;
    },
    ""
  );
  inputs.forEach(function(input, index) {
    input.value = text.charAt(index);
    if (!focussed && !input.value) {
    console.log("Focussing " + this.name);
     input.focus();
      focussed = true;
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="password" name="pin1" autofocus />
  <input type="password" name="pin2" />
  <input type="password" name="pin3" />
  <input type="password" name="pin4" />
</form>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Isn't change & keypress events redundant here if already using `input` event? And here, this doesn't handle only numeric values, right?

Comment: @A.Wolff: I'm being paranoid about older browsers that don't support `input`. :-)

Comment: So you should add `paste` and maybe `mouseup` (for drag) events, if im' correct :)

Comment: @A.Wolff: Good point. If I were doing this on a project, I'd have to research these again relative to current browser usage.

Comment: Why do you use `setTimeout`?

Comment: @user3142695: On a `keypress`, the new character hasn't been added to the `input` yet, so we need to let the event complete and *then* read the value of the inputs.

Comment: Understand. And where do I check for the typed value - as I only want to allow numeric values?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I'd use btw `var keyPressed = String.fromCharCode(event.which);` instead of a timeout. And then this can be easily test against a regex to get only numeric value and in case not, prevent default behaviour. Problem is that `input` event doesn't handle any `event.which`, maybe check against `this.value.slice(0, 1)` instead

Comment: @user3142695: I've updated the code block to show where you'd operate on `text` before distributing its (remaining) content.

Answer (score 1):

You could just add the code you have on the keyup event trigger on keydown.

```
$('input').on('keydown', function(event) {   
    if (event.shiftKey || event.which <= 47 || event.which >= 58) {
        return false;
    }
    if (event.currentTarget.value.length >= 1) {
        $(event.currentTarget).next('input').focus();
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bbeg17r8/2/

Comment: Nice. But if I type "12", the focus should be after this on the third input field.

Answer (score 0):

This what you could use to handle all (i can think) situations:

```
$("input").on('change keyup paste', function(event) {
  if(event.which === 9) return; // tab pressed, keep default behaviour
  var char = this.value.slice(0, 1);
  if (!/\d/.test(char)) this.value = "";
  else $(this).next('input').focus();
});
```

### -jsFiddle-

  *(using inputs type text to make it clearer)*

PS: i'm tired of jsFiddle not updating correct one. Since lastest jsFiddle major update, this is really bugging me...